# Subquery returns unexpected results with WHERE, but works fine with JOIN

Tags: sql, join, subquery, where-clause, h2

I want to get random quotes from db, I'm using this query:

`SELECT * FROM quote WHERE quote.id = (SELECT id FROM quote ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1)`

but I didn't get result time to time. Seems like subquery returns id that is not exists.

Subquery is working fine separately. And I didn't get id that is not exists.

And this query with JOIN instead WHERE works fine too.

`SELECT * FROM quote JOIN (SELECT id FROM quote ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) q1 ON quote.id = q1.id`

**Note:** I can't use just subquery that returns whole quote, because I need to use some addition JOINs in main query. With these JOINs and without - result is the same.

Comment: i would guess that there a NULL results in your table, random numbers are that, you could 100 times the same id or every time another id, so a proof that your second query works every time, is only a guess

Comment: @nbk yeah, I think I have some NULL results, but I don't understand why subquery work fine separately? I mean it always returns ids that is exist

Comment: @nbk I have three records in table and I can't got empty result with JOIN how long I didn't run query. On the other side I got empty results 50/50 with WHERE

Comment: when the subwuery return NULL, you can't comapre it with =

Comment: as i explained randon doesn't work that way, you could that that three NULL every time you run the first query and never in the second.

Comment: educated guess: h2 can't decide wether the subquery is static or depends on main query, so it is executed for every record. So it only returns a result when the current record is the  first record of the subquery, what is sheer luck

Comment: @Turo so how can we overcome it? Can we clearly mark that is a static?

Comment: What's wrong with the join version, why don't you want to use that?

Comment: @Turo I think JOIN will be slower, but yeah if I won't figure out with WHERE that I will use JOIN

Comment: There is no reason to think that join is slower. In a lot of cases a subquery gets converted to a join from the optimizer to make it faster...
You could help the optimzer by chaenging sides of the join and make it an outer join, If it shpuld pick the wrong access path

Comment: If you wanted to confirm the no result, you could use something like coalesce to handle a null return to produce a predictable value that should not otherwise be returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a big difference between a **subquery** in the `WHERE` criteria of the first query and a **derived table** from table expression of the second query. They only look the same.

1. `RAND()` function is non-deterministic, non-deterministic functions may return different results for the same arguments. Usage of this function in a subquery makes the whole subquery non-deteministic. Non-deterministic subqueries are executed every time when their values are needed and here they are actually needed multiple times.

   When outer query reads a row, it needs to verify that it matches the `WHERE` criteria, but non-deterministic subquery returns random results and this check will fail if `id` of checked row is different from random `id` returned from a subquery.

   *If `id` column is indexed (most likely it is), the subquery is executed first time to create an index condition and second time to check the `WHERE` criteria, if it isn't, the subquery is executed for each row from the first table to check the same `WHERE` criteria, in either case the outer query may return no results.*
2. When the second query (with a join) is executed, its table value expressions, including that derived table, are constructed **first**, before any other steps of query execution. So there is only one execution of `SELECT id FROM quote ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`, a derived table produced by this inner query isn't modified after that, so everything works as you expect.